# Why i don't get the string in one index?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

When I try to insert a string to an array I get `['.','p','y']` instead of `[.py]`:

```
from os import walk
Typofiles=[]
t=""
Ex=""
f = []
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk('D:\Python_Scripts'):
    f.extend(filenames)
for i in range(1):
    t = f[i]
    indexO=t.rindex('.')
    LenF=len(t)
    Ex=(t[-(LenF-indexO):])
    if Ex in Typofiles:
        pass
    else:
        Typofiles.extend(Ex)

print (Typofiles)
print(Ex)
```

The result is: `['.','p','y']` how can I get `['.py']`?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `Typofiles` is a list and you are using the `.extend` method. The `.extend` method of a list takes an iterable, and appends each element of the iterable to itself. Thus, it looks something like this:

```
class List:
    def extend(self, iterable):
        for elem in iterable:
            self.append(elem)
```

Since `Ex` is a string, it is an iterable, and thus goes through the above process. What you want to do instead, is use the `.append` method, which simply adds the element to the list, whatever the element may be:

```
In [19]: L = []

In [20]: L.extend('.py')

In [21]: L
Out[21]: ['.', 'p', 'y']

In [22]: L = []

In [23]: L.append('.py')

In [24]: L
Out[24]: ['.py']
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `extend`ing a list causes every element in the iterable argument to be appended separately:

> `L.extend(iterable) -> None` -- extend list by appending elements from the iterable

```
l = []    
l.extend(".py")
print(l)  # ['.', 'p', 'y']
```

you're looking for `.append` which takes the object and simply places it at the end of the list:

```
l = []    
l.append(".py")
print(l)  # ['.py']
```